# Center Image in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Does anybody know a possibility to center simple pictures within a UIWebview without using hmtl/css?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible -- a `UIWebView` displays web content, nothing else. Use a `UIImageView` if you need to display images in your application.

Edit: Noah's comment had me look further into this, and it is possible to load local files using the `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:`, but I'm not sure what the centering situation is there. `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` is the easiest way to get this functionality, but of course you were asking how to do it without html/css.

Comment: `UIWebView` can be given a URL to an image or PDF in the filesystem or elsewhere, and will display it just fine; it's an easy solution for those who don't feel like coding up a whole `UIScrollView`-based panning/zooming mechanism. `UIImageView` is by no means the only way to display images.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't involve HTML, you can center images in a UIWebView in only Objective-C, kind of.  There is a really direct bridge to **anything** you can do in JavaScript, HTML, CSS, or anything else with the WebKit API (the framework behind UIWebView and related classes).  Furthermore, WebKit constructs a full document, the same as you might do with HTML, for when it presents non-HTML documents. (I can't confirm this for all types of media, but absolutely can for images.)  Therefore, you can center an image loaded directly from a resource URL by executing javascript such as the following:

```
 var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
 img.style.margin="auto";
 img.style.display="block"
```

(you can test this in Safari by loading the image then entering in the titlebar "javascript:var img = document..." where you include the full javascript on one line, and then hitting enter).  Anyways, in your actual app, you just need to

```
 -[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script]
```

(with the above script being (NSString *)script, obviously), to center the image as loaded directly from an image URL.  Note: this will only work for horizontal centering, not vertical.  There is probably a way to do that as well, but it is likely substantially more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Swift
First action = webView.navigationDelegate = self

and

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        let cssString = "html,body { height: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }"
        let jsString = "var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '\(cssString)'; document.head.appendChild(style);"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)

}
```